# Uploading image and displaying it in Image control

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the problem with my code?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stream = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string sub = stream.Substring(stream.LastIndexOf(".")+1);
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (sub == "jpg" || sub == "jpeg" || sub == "png")
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("./Image/" + stream);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
            Image1.ImageUrl = path;
            Image1.DataBind();
        }
        else 
        {
            Response.Write("Please insert valid Image");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't user dot in start of path.

Comment: Was this a trick question or something? If not, then always explain what error you're getting and why there should be a problem in your code.

Comment: after clicking, I do not get any error and the image save in the path correctly, but the image not loading in Image control and image control show me nothing

Answer (score 0):

Remove that dot (.) in the starting of your path string.

Make it like this :

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/Image/" + stream);
```

Also make sure that the path is proper and that file is uploaded. You can try for relative Url if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What error are you getting and at which line of code ?

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/Image/1.png'.

Comment: string path = Server.MapPath("/Image/" + stream);
Line 33:                         FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
Line 34:                         Image1.ImageUrl = path;

Comment: Try putting a `~` (tilt) sign before that path like this : `Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + stream);`

Comment: dot (.) in the path in not a problem. Single dot points to current directory, double dot (..) to parent directory.

Comment: Did you try putting tilt sign `~` ?

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = path;
```

with the following:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}/Image/{2}",
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme,
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority, stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ImageUrl to be an internet url instead of physical path.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/Image/" + stream; //path;
//Image1.DataBind(); <-- remove it
```

P.S.

You can also use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(stream)` to get extension such as ".jpg" (with leading dot in it).